# Android preference defautvalue duplicate resource

Tags: android, settings, androidx, preferenceactivity

I want to make a settings activity for an android app. I used the standard activity for the settings but I keep getting the error:

```
\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\e3ce7e7cf0568bf54350349961cc10db\preference-1.1.1\res\values\values.xml:257:5-336:25: AAPT: error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/defaultValue' with config ''.
```

I think it has something to do with the `androidx.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat` because the error disappears when I remove the dependency on `android.preference:preference:1.1.1`. Do you know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The `DevaultValue` was already defined by me in the `res/attr/` folder. deleting this value makes it work.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a field with **defaultValue** in attrs file, rename it and try rebuild it. It works